# How to update symmetric, positive definite matrix in the constrained Hamiltonian Monte Carlo algorithm?

Tags: monte-carlo, covariance-matrix, constraint

## original post

I'm working on the implementation of the Hamiltonian Monte Carlo (HMC) algorithm which includes a covariance matrix parameter, say $\Sigma$.

Let $\Phi$ be the (initialized) momentum parameter for $\Sigma$. Then, the first step would be the half-step for the momemtum as follows.
$$\Phi \leftarrow \Phi - \epsilon / 2 \cdot \frac{d\ell}{d\Sigma}$$
Next, the parameter will be updated within the leap-frog steps.

$$\Sigma \leftarrow \Sigma - \epsilon / 2 \cdot \Phi$$

The covariance matrix should be positive-definite (later used in the computation of log-likelihood), and thus how do we keep the restriction on the covariance matrix?

## Update (20.02.03)

This problem is related to the constrained HMC. Have anyone seen examples using the parameter defined over the positive definite cone?

Any comment would help me a lot :D

Comment: it's not strictly the same as constrained HMC - in constrained HMC, you typically have a hard constraint, i.e. $f (\Sigma) = 0$ for some function $f$. in your case, you have an inequality constraint, which is qualitatively different. i think the solution will depend a bit on the character of your problem, but most likely you will want to use a different integrator scheme.

Comment: @πr8 +1, for indicating the difference.